Collapse of Moebius bands with bounded below Gauss curvature and convex boundary
Let $\{M_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of (compact) Moebius bands with Riemannian metrics with Gauss curvature at least $-1$ and such that the boundaries are geodesically convex (equivalently, the second fundamental forms of $\partial M_i$ are non-negative).
Question. Can $\{M_i\}$ converge in the Gromov-Hausdorff metric to a segment?

Suppose your Moebius band is a rectangle $[0,1]\times[0,a]$ with glued $[0,1]\times{0}$ and $[0,1]\times{a}$. By sending $a\to 0$, you get a collapse to $[0,\tfrac12]$.

@Petrunin: Oops, you are right. Thank you. This is the final answer.
